# HTML layout: adding sidebar column to existing site

Tags: css, css-float, html, html-table

I have a site with a body that looks like that:

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

No absolute / relative positioning tricks are used in these `div`s, but there are a lot of `float`s, `clear`s, `margin`s and `padding`s in styles of these `div`s and their inner elements. All this yields a site that looks like that:

```
┌───────────────┐
│     header    │
└───────────────┘
┌───────────────┐
│    content    │
└───────────────┘
┌───────────────┐
│     footer    │
└───────────────┘
```

My question is: how do I add one independent fixed-width left column (sidebar) with extra content that would contract whole site (header-content-footer) and shift them to the right.

```
┌────┐┌─────────┐
│side││ header  │
│bar │└─────────┘
│    │┌─────────┐
│    ││ content │
│    │└─────────┘
│    │┌─────────┐
│    ││ footer  │
└────┘└─────────┘
```

I know of one almost-ideal solution, but it is ugly and requires re-nesting existing divs:

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="sidebar">...</td>
      <td>
        <div id="header">...</div>
        <div id="content">...</div>
        <div id="footer">...</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Is it possible to do so elegantly, just adding one external sidebar element somewhere in body, i.e., like that?

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">...</div>
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

I've tried naive approaches - such as styling:

```css
#sidebar { float: left; width: 20em; }
```

or

```css
#header { margin-left: 20em; }
#content { margin-left: 20em; }
#footer { margin-left: 20em; }
```

This kind of works, but it breaks as soon `clear: both` or `clear: left` is encountered  in header/content/footer.

So, are there any alternatives to table solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like to use an absolutely positioned sidebar, then set the padding on the wrapper to the width of that element. Then I either set the margin-padding on the other elements, or I add it to the padding on the wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/jAVQv/

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.container { position:relative; padding:0 0 0 55px; }
#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; bottom:0; left:0;
    width:50px;
    background:#000;
}

#header { border:1px solid #000; width:100px; height:20px; 
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
#content { border:1px solid #000; width:100px; height:50px;
    margin:5px 0 5px 0;
}
#footer { border:1px solid #000; width:100px; height:20px;
    margin:5px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution also includes re-nesting header/content/footer, but at least it's not as cumbersome as the table-based solution. Is it possible at all to retain header/content/footer in `body`? I guess it should be possible to style `body` with relative position and a padding?

Comment: Here you go, your solution also works on `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/jAVQv/1/ - looks like it's exactly what I need here. I understand that styling `body` is a bad practice, but I guess it's better than all the alternatives (i.e. re-nesting) in this case.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use HTML5 elements to give the markup semantic meaning.

```
<body>
  <aside><!-- Nav bar --></aside>
  <article>
    <header>...</header>
    <section>...</section>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </article>
</body>
```

Then style `aside` and `article` with `float: left`.

Answer (score 2):

I made a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FbQZx/) to help you getting started. Also you might want to check if your div contents aren't messing up the whole CSS. Hope this helps.

Edit : all colors and dimensions are dummy ones used for the example. It shoudk work with any dimension.

html :

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">...</div>
  <div id="header">
      <div id="testLeft"></div>
      <div id="testRight"></div>
      <div class="clearFix"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
```

css :

```css
.clearFix {
    clear: both;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
}

#header {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 55px;
}

#testLeft {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: pink;
}

#testRight {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 55px;
    background-color: purple;
}

#content {
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 55px;
}

#footer {
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-left: 55px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. It perfectly illustrates exactly what I'm talking about: `clear` does break things here - if you'll make sidebar height much longer, header will become giant: http://jsfiddle.net/FbQZx/1/

Comment: The problem doesn't occur anymore whenever I set a defined height for the header : [http://jsfiddle.net/FbQZx/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/FbQZx/1/)

Comment: You don't seem to have updated anything (probably haven't saved?) Moreover, setting fixed height for the header (or content, or footer) is not an option for my case - especially for content.

Comment: My bad, I didn't save indeed. I don't need update since you can't use any fixed height anyways.