# height with percentage(%) broke page

Tags: html, css

Look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/on10qewb/3/

I need to put the sidebar to the top right, but if I use float right, it juts moves the sidebar to the right(but not top right).

I need to make the position absolute approach, it's easier for me, but what happend if I put the class "mega" to height 100%? the footer goes below the the class "main" and I don't know why

```css
    html,body{height: 100%;}
        body{margin: 0;
            padding: 0;}
    .main{height: 100%;
          background: #eee;
          border-radius: 5px;
          box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #000;}
        .mega{padding: 5px;
            position: relative;
    /*this breaks everything(footer is below "main" div)
    height: 100%; 
    */
    height: 100%; 
        }
        .new{width: 50%;
        background: #000;
        }
        .box{display: inline-block;
              margin: 5px;
              width: 100px;
              height: 60px;
              box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #000;
                  background: tomato;
    }
    
        .sidebar{width: 30%;
                 margin: 10px;
                 height: 30px;
                 background: royalblue;
                 box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #000;}
        footer{
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0 10px;
        background: gold;}
```

```html
    <div class="main">
        <div class="mega">
            <div class="new">
               <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
                <div class="box">box</div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
            
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your `mega` has 100% height, so obviously `footer` will go beyond! Place `footer` inside `mega` and absoutely position `sidebar`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/on10qewb/4/. I would suggest, you first draw out things first on paper and open your computer afterwards.

Comment: @abhitalks why not you post your answer as you did it in jsfiddle??

Comment: see this question it is good example for layouts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147887/html-layout-adding-sidebar-column-to-existing-site

Comment: @Muhammad: Please go ahead and post as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a height of 100%, that div takes a height of 100% of it's parent div. So if you say main is 100%, and mega is 100%, it will expand to fill the entire main div, forcing the footer to be outside than the main div. There are a couple ways to fix this. You could nest your footer inside of mega, bringing it's height within that 100%. Or you could give mega a pixel height, and the footer will be offset by that height.

Answer (score 0):

Floating the sidebar positions it below the `.new` element because `.new` is not being floated. You would need to float both elements to get them side by side.

http://jsfiddle.net/on10qewb/5/

Also, be sure to properly indent your code when you're looking for help - it makes things much easier.